# Hi, Can we store Big XML file into azure sql db using power automate?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, power-automate

I need to store xml file from blob to azure sql db. Can I put it in single column in my db?

Comment: What do you mean by single column ? Please share expected output.

Answer (score 0):

To insert xml file data from blob storage to SQL database, follow below steps

**Step1:** Upload XML file to blob storage

[image]

**Step2:** Create table in SQL database.

[image]

**Step3:** Create copy activity in Azure Data Factory

[image]

**Step4:** Add Blob storage as a Source

[image]

**Step5:** Add SQL database as a Sink

[image]

**Step6:** Do the mappings

[image]

**Step7:** Now you can run copy activity and get required output as shown in below image.

[image]